# Quickfixj 1.5.x/1.6.x custom message with repeating group - compilation issue

Tags: quickfixj

i am trying to add a custom message and compile quickfixj and am running into an issue where last few fields that i've added are not being picked up (they all have field number > 93000 if it matters)

code generation is ok but compilation fails, i am sure i am missing something obvious, searched for similar issues reported by others but didn't find any, can someone please help

#

public static class NoAccounts extends Group {

```
    static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;
    private static final int[] ORDER = {1, 51006, 90002, 90003, 51005, 90001, 93000, , , , , , , 0};
```

#

Here is what i've added

```
<message name="GetAccountsRsp" msgtype="UsE" msgcat="app">
  <field name="RequestId" required="Y"/>
  <field name="ResponseStatus" required="N"/>
  <field name="ErrorMessage" required="N"/>
  <component name="AccountGrp" required="N"/>
  <field name="Bookmark" required="N"/>
  <field name="LastFragment" required="Y"/>
</message>

<component name="AccountGrp">
  <group name="NoAccounts" required="N">
    <field name="Account" required="N"/>
    <field name="RiskNodeID" required="N"/>
    <field name="Name" required="N"/>
    <field name="AutomaticMoveAccountId" required="N"/>
    <field name="Owner" required="N"/>
    <field name="JSCCAccountType" required="N"/>
    <component name="AccountExtension" required="N"/>
  </group>    
</component>
<component name="AccountExtension">
  <field name="JpxAccountType" required="N"/>
  <field name="IsOmnibus" required="N"/>
  <field name="IsGross" required="N"/>
  <field name="ClientId" required="N"/>
  <field name="TradingMemberId" required="N"/>
  <field name="ClearingMemberId" required="N"/>
  <field name="IsConcentration" required="N"/>
</component>

<field number="50007" name="Bookmark" type="STRING"/>
<field number="50025" name="RequestId" type="STRING"/>
<field number="51005" name="Owner" type="STRING"/>
<field number="51006" name="RiskNodeID" type="STRING"/>
<field number="51009" description="ClearingMemberId" type="STRING" />
<field number="51011" description="TradingMemberId" type="STRING" />
<field number="51015" name="ResponseStatus" type="STRING">
  <value enum="0" description="ACCEPTED" />
  <value enum="1" description="REJECTED" />
</field>
<field number="51016" name="ErrorMessage" type="STRING"/>
<field number="51019" name="NoAccounts" type="NUMINGROUP"/>
<field number="90001" name="JSCCAccountType" type="STRING">
  <value enum="1" description="DEFAULT_CLEARING_HOUSE" />
  <value enum="2" description="CLEARING_HOUSE" />
  <value enum="3" description="NORMAL" />
  <value enum="4" description="CONCENTRATION" />
</field>
<field number="90002" name="Name" type="STRING"/>
<field number="90003" name="AutomaticMoveAccountId" type="STRING"/>
<field number="93000" name="JpxAccountType" type="STRING">
  <value enum="1" description="HOUSE_ACCOUNT_TYPE" />
  <value enum="2" description="AFFILIATE_ACCOUNT_TYPE" />
  <value enum="3" description="CLIENT_ACCOUNT_TYPE" />
</field>
<field number="93001" description="IsOmnibus" type="BOOLEAN">
  <value enum="N" description="FALSE"/>
  <value enum="Y" description="TRUE"/>
</field>
<field number="93002" description="IsGross" type="BOOLEAN">
  <value enum="N" description="FALSE"/>
  <value enum="Y" description="TRUE"/>
</field>
<field number="93003" description="ClientId" type="STRING" />
<field number="93015" description="IsConcentration" type="BOOLEAN">
  <value enum="N" description="FALSE"/>
  <value enum="Y" description="TRUE"/>  
</field>
<field number="96005" name="ContractPeriod" type="INT"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

please ignore, stupid error, I've added 'description' attribute instead of 'name' attribute to the new fields I've added, when I include in group/component source is generated without these causing an issue during compilation. lesson learned - double check dictionary to avoid issues during recompilation